# Populate people picker during PreSaveAction in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property

I want to auto populate user manager name from employee column which is a people picker column. I am able to get all properties and able to fetch user profile properties as well using below code but how to populate base on employee name which is people picker

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        getItems();     
    });

    function getItems() {
        //alert("djdj")
        var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
        $.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var Manager = data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[17].Value;
                console.log(Manager);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is it OOTB list form ? or your custom form

Comment: its outbox list form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working fine, Inspired by answer from @Hellofiano_MSFT

```
     <script>
      function PreSaveAction() {
   GetValuePeoplePicker();
    return true;
}

    function getUserManager(username){
        var manager="";
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='"+username+"'";
        $.ajax({
             url: requestUri,
             method: "GET",
             async:false,
             headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
             success: function (data) {
                manager = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;    
                SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("Manager", manager)      
             },
             error: function (data) {
             }
         });
        return manager;
    }



    function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userName) {
        var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
        var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
        var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title^='" + fieldName + "']");
        _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);
        var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
        _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
    }
function GetValuePeoplePicker(fieldName) {
    var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
    var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
    var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title^='" + fieldName + "']");

    var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
   var userinfo = _PeoplePickerOject.GetAllUserInfo();
   console.log(userinfo);
   console.log(userinfo[0].EntityData.Email);
   getUserManager(userinfo[0].EntityData.Email)  
}

    </script>
```

Comment: thank you siddharth , it work for current user login name any way to find on sharepoint presave i want to get  employee manager and employee is my people picker field in list form,

Comment: what you need is your employees username...pass it to getUserManager field..let me check and edit answer.

Comment: thank you it is working

Comment: please upvote and mark it as answer if it was helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the script as below:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
    PopulateManager();
    return true;
}
function PopulateManager() {
    var nominees = $(".sp-peoplepicker-userSpan[id*='Nomination_x0028_s_x0029']");
    $.each(nominees, function(index,value){
        var username = $(value).attr("sid").split("|")[1];
        var manager=getUserManager(username);
        SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("Managers", manager);    
    });
}
function getUserManager(username){
    var manager="";
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='"+username+"'";
    $.ajax({
         url: requestUri,
         method: "GET",
         async:false,
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
         success: function (data) {
            manager = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;         
         },
         error: function (data) {
         }
     });
    return manager;
}
function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userName) {
    var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
    var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
    var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title^='" + fieldName + "']");
    _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);
    var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
    _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
}
</script>
```

Reference: [Populate people picker during PreSaveAction](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250363/populate-people-picker-during-presaveaction)

Comment: i already tried above script giving me below error

Comment: Object expected